# Different urls for the same tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

and

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript

the same thing, or are they different ones?

If it's the same then why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are simply two paths to the same action. I wouldn't be surprised if one controller action just redirects to the other controller's action.

I can only speculate to why it's like that; but I do know there are two paths to get there:

1. Click on `Tags` and click on `JavaScript`
2. Click on `Questions` and click on `JavaScript` (on the right hand side of the page.

A user that wants to navigate by tag first is different than a user that navigates questions and clicks on a tag they might want to find out more about when they're in a question.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, there *could* be a potential difference. For instance, the second link, that points to the tag, instead of the questions tagged with that tag, could potentially include information about the tag, like why it is there, what it stands for, what it is used for, etc.

At the moment though, it appears they're quite equivalent, but I guess the final word has to come from the SO team members themselves.